# Non-test methods in a Python TestCase

Tags: python, unit-testing

Ok, as Google search isn't helping me in a while (even when using the correct keywords).

I have a class extending from TestCase in which I want to have some auxiliary methods that are not going to be executed as part of the test, they'll be used to generate some mocked objects, etc, auxiliary things for almost any test.

I know I could use the @skip decorator so unittest doesn't run a particular test method, but I think that's an ugly hack to use for my purpose, any tips?

Thanks in advance, community :D

Comment: Doesn't unit test only run tests for methods starting with "test_"?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

I believe that you don't have to do anything.  Your helper methods should just not start with `test_`.

Comment: @piva: Read the unittest documentation at http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html, specifically

"TestLoader uses the 'test' method name prefix to identify test methods automatically."

Comment: @daveydave400 Yeap, dumb question of mine, but in a hurry my eyes rushed through the text

Comment: /aside Every now and then, I forget to prefix a test method with `test_`, and it takes me a while to figure out why it isn't being run by the test runner.

Comment: Coming from a Java background: I don't understand why unittest does not use a @decorator for tests, just like JUnit 4 does, it's so much readable and clean than just some convention on names...

Answer (score 5):

The only methods that unittest will execute [1] are `setUp`, anything that starts with `test`, and `tearDown` [2], in that order. You can make helper methods and call them anything except for those three things, and they will not be executed by unittest.

You can think of `setUp` as `__init__`: if you're generating mock objects that are used by multiple tests, create them in `setUp`.

```
def setUp(self):
    self.mock_obj = MockObj()
```

[1]: This is not entirely true, but these are the main 3 groups of methods that you can concentrate on when writing tests.

[2]: For legacy reasons, unittest will execute both `test_foo` and `testFoo`, but `test_foo` is the preferred style these days. `setUp` and `tearDown` should appear as such.

Answer (score 3):

The test runner will only directly execute methods beginning with `test`, so just make sure your helper methods' names don't begin with `test`.